# Aligning font awesome icons beside text

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How do I align the icons with a clean look? My code is pasted below. and look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOGiY.jpg) but i want it to look like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob68Z.jpg)

I tried to put it in table then align left with each td but the icons are moved down. Any possible way? thanks

```
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> July 25, 2017</p>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> Sample City</p>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-venus-mars"></span> Male</p>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span> sample-email@gmail.com</p>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> +12 34567890</p>
```

Comment: Please css code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Font Awesome [Fixed Width Icons (`fa-fw`)](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons) or [List Icons (`fa-ul` + `fa-li`)](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p><u><code>fa-fw</code> class</u></p>
<p><span class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></span> July 25, 2017</p>
<p><span class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw"></span> Sample City</p>
<p><span class="fa fa-venus-mars fa-fw"></span> Male</p>
<p><span class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></span> sample-email@gmail.com</p>
<p><span class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></span> +12 34567890</p>

<p><u><code>fa-ul</code> + <code>fa-li</code> class</u></p>
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa fa-calendar fa-li"></span> July 25, 2017</li>
  <li><span class="fa fa-map-marker fa-li"></span> Sample City</li>
  <li><span class="fa fa-venus-mars fa-li"></span> Male</li>
  <li><span class="fa fa-envelope fa-li"></span> sample-email@gmail.com</li>
  <li><span class="fa fa-phone fa-li"></span> +12 34567890</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: can i use my custom icon from my png file ?

Comment: @calvinsugianto Ask this in a new SO question. 

Answer (score 1):

adding style to your `span` tag will fix it

```css
span {
 width: 10px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> July 25, 2017</p>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> Sample City</p>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-venus-mars"></span> Male</p>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span> sample-email@gmail.com</p>
<p class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> +12 34567890</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, something like this,

```
<ul>
<li class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> July 25, 2017</li>
<li class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> Sample City</li>
<li class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-venus-mars"></span> Male</li>
<li class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span> sample-email@gmail.com</li>
<li class="for-font-size"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> +12 34567890</li>
</ul>
```

You can also remove the `class="for-font-size"` if not required.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
.for-font-size .fa {
    width: 15px; (arrording to font-size)
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

So mean people, why so many downvote...

```
.fa {
  min-width:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
```