# How do I place a FontAwesome Icon right next to text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, font-awesome-5

I am using a FontAwesome's Icon. The icon is showing up on the line above and not next to the text as seen here:

[image: Menu]

relevant code:

```
<div className="block col-1">
    <p><span><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} className="fa-fw" /><h5>My Account</h5></span></p>
    <hr />
    <p><a>Dashboard</a></p>
    <p><div role="menuitem" onClick={this.showInvoices.bind(this)}>Invoices</div></p>
    <p><div role="menuitem" onClick={this.showOrders.bind(this)}>Orders</div></p>
</div>
```

I have tried using the fixed-width class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301774/aligning-font-awesome-icons-beside-text/45301895), with no change. I have also tried `float: left`, that put it on the same line but made it go the the far left edge. I also tried widening my menu div. What am I missing?

Comment: try this `<p><span style={{display: 'flex'}}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} className="fa-fw" /><h5>My Account</h5></span></p>`

Comment: The easiest solution is probably putting the `FontAwesome` tag inside the `h5` tag

Comment: @SaadMehmood that's not semantic HTML. Block elements should not be inside inline elements.

Comment: `<h5>` will have `display: block` by default, forcing it on to it's own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h5` element is a block element, that means it is going to be the only element in that line.
Place the `<FontAwesomeIcon />` into the `<h5 />` and it should work:

```
<div className="block col-1">
    <h5>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} className="fa-fw" />My Account
    </h5>
    <hr />
    <p><a>Dashboard</a></p>
    <p><div role="menuitem" onClick={this.showInvoices.bind(this)}>Invoices</div></p>
    <p><div role="menuitem" onClick={this.showOrders.bind(this)}>Orders</div></p>
</div>
```

PS: The `<span />` and the `<p />` in that line are not necessary IMO.

Comment: Not only is the `span` unnecessary, it's not proper HTML to put a block element inside an inline element